# How to exclude rsync excludes from delete?

Tags: linux, command-line, rsync

I'm using rsync to sync files across multiple machines, using the following:

```
rsync -az -e "ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no" \
  --delete --delete-excluded --force --exclude=.git  --exclude=.bundle \
  --exclude=tmp --exclude=log/* --exclude=*.log --exclude=*.pid \
  user@host:/path/to/src/ /var/build/dest
```

I want to exclude all log files from being transferred from the source to destination, and delete all existing ones on the destination. So I'm using `--exclude=*.log` with `--delete-excluded` which works great.

**But** I want to keep a certain log file intact on the destination. I want an `--exclude-from-delete` option.

Is this possible with rsync?

Comment: Similar: [How to use rsync to backup a directory without git subdirectory?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/100660/21471)

Answer (score 53):

The "protect" filter should accomplish just what you want:

```
          protect, P specifies a pattern for protecting files from deletion.
```

Just specify the following filter before the relevant excludes:

```
--filter='P my-specific-logfile.log'
```

(Notice the space after the letter P.)

Comment: This actually works.